# apex:selectList always passing older value on onchange..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, actionsupport

I am using apex:selectList..I want to get the value on onchange of the selectlist..But for first time when i am debugging the value..Its blank..ID comes when i change it again(Second time)..But its the previous value..If i change it again..It again shows the previous value,not the new value and so on..
So it gives me the old value.?`

Please help Its urgent

**{!hr.p}** The value get refreshed on the VF page but not in the controler

**Updated**

```
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperTimeCardList}" var="hr" id="thePbTable">
       <apex:column >
        <apex:selectList value="{!hr.p}" size="1" multiselect="false" onchange="proIp('{!hr.pp}');">

                              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!taks}" reRender="thePb">
                                   <apex:param name="prId"  value="{!hr.p}"  assignTo="{!proIdVal}" ></apex:param>
                               </apex:actionSupport>
                               Project: <apex:selectOptions value="{!hr.projectListOptions}"/>
                          </apex:selectList>`
    </apex:column >
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    public void fp()
        {

             **value is blank here for First time,then old value always.???**


        }


**Wrapper Class**

    public List<wrapperliass> wrappeList{get;set;}
        public class wlass{
            public List<Selectoption> prOptions{get;set;}
            public List<Selectoption> pListOptions{get;set;}
            public String pVal{get;set;}
            public String prskVal{get;set;}

            Public blob fileData{get;set;}


            public wrapperTimeCardClass(List<Selectoption> Options,List<Selectoption> ptions,
                                                               ){
                this.prptions=tOptions;
                this.proOptions=projectTaions; 
                this.projVal='';                                   

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your reference twice hr.projectVal, that's why it's getting confused, one in your select and one in your param. Remove your param and it should fix your problem, it's useless.

**Update**

```
Project: <apex:selectList value="{!hr.projectVal}" size="1" multiselect="false">
                      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!fillProjectTasks}" reRender="thePb"/>
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!hr.projectListOptions}"/>
                  </apex:selectList>


public void fillProjectTasks()
{
proIdVal = hr.projectVal; 
System.debug('============proIdVal======'+proIdVal);
     **value is blank here for First time,then old value always.???**


}
```

Comment: Yeah of course you need to assign in your controller

Comment: prodIdVal = hr.projectVal in fillProjectVal

Comment: I only want to get the changed select list value..Can you help me ...How do i get that,?As its a list.??How to get which one user has changed.?

Comment: I updated my answer for you

Comment: Hey brovasi...  wrapperTimeCardList is a wrapper list and projectVal is the variable of that wrapper class...If i do like this proIdVal = hr.projectVal; If my wrapperlist has 2 records...always last value will come..not the changed one..?You got my issue.

Comment: what's 'hr'??????

Comment: Sorry your issue was not very clear.

Comment: Sorry i forgot the pageblocktable..I just updated my question...Please see that..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25225/discussion-between-miku-and-brovasi).